# WildFly 14 - java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly

I have an application that runs on WildFly 8.2.1.Final release perfectly, there is no problem. But I wanna upgrade the server version from 8.2.1.Final to 14.0.1.Final and after adding datasources to 14.0.1.Final, I'm starting application and getting below error.

- I tried to add provided scope to hibernate-core dependency but not solved.
- I tried to add dom4j as maven dependency but not solved.
- I deleted dom4j.jar from WildFly modules and added as maven dependency, but this time I got module loading problem.

What is the solution for this problem?

```
13:32:25,121 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."warName.war#persistenceUnitName": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."warName.war#persistenceUnitName": java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:125)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:650)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:209)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1985)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1487)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1378)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:485)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    at org.dom4j.DocumentFactory.getInstance(DocumentFactory.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:33)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper$1.doWork(XMLHelper.java:27)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.workWithClassLoader(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:483)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.XMLHelper.<init>(XMLHelper.java:26)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl.initialize(EnversServiceImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.produceAdditionalMappings(AdditionalJaxbMappingProducerImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:297)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:904)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:935)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate5.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:44)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:167)
    ... 9 more

13:32:25,133 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "warName.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"warName.war#persistenceUnitName\"" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}
13:32:25,135 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server] (management-handler-thread - 1) WFLYSRV0021: Deploy of deployment "warName.war" was rolled back with the following failure message: 
{"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"warName.war#persistenceUnitName\"" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}
13:32:25,155 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 17) WFLYJPA0011: Stopping Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'warName.war#persistenceUnitName'
13:32:25,376 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-6) WFLYSRV0028: Stopped deployment authentication.war (runtime-name: warName.war) in 241ms
[2018-10-20 01:32:25,481] Artifact module:war: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
[2018-10-20 01:32:25,482] Artifact module:war: java.lang.Exception: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"warName.war#persistenceUnitName\"" => "java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory"}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found a possible solution at https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-5549

Basicly add a jboss-deployment-structure.xml which adds a dependency to module org.dom4j

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="org.dom4j"/>
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Also check your lib folder in the war.
Remove all hibernate related jars. Also the dom4j
Wildfly already provides them.
In the hibernate module modules/system/layers/base/org/hibernate/main/module.xml a dependency to org.dom4j is set.

Answer (score 1):

Modify the dependency hibernate-core in the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Add the `exclusion` tag. Then Clean and Build. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, problem was caused by having added 2 drivers in standalone.xml, one pointing to ojdbc6 and one to ojdbc7 (distributed from oracle), and exposed in wf14 as modules.
Even if i exclude dom4j, or if i import from pom or from jboss-deployment-structure.xml, exception was still there.

After removing the older driver (updating datasources that were using it), and keeping only ojdbc7, exception disappeared.

Hope it helps.